# AWS security groups and Virtual private cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services

Can instance1 and instance2 with default security groups communicate with each other if they are in different vpc and in same region?

Comment: What architecture are you wanting to achieve? If you describe your end-goal, we might be able to recommend an appropriate approach.

Comment: you can achieve this using vpc peering and adding a route table to individuals vpc's  .

Answer (score 1):

EC2 instances can't communicate with each other using their private IPs unless both VPCs are peered.

Once Peering is established which includes addition of route table entires for CIDR ranges of peer VPC, pointing to peering connection, then each VPC know where to route requests to when private instances from one vpc tries to talk to private ip of other vpc.